# Not able to handle number whose length is more than 10

Tags: java, long-integer, primitive-types

I know that max value for `int` and `long` are very high but somehow I am not able to handle them in my code. I am getting compilation error in all the scenarios below. Could someone please suggest how I can handle `20118998631` value.

I know that if I put `l` after this value `20118998631l` then declaring it as long will work but problem is that I am getting this from a network call and if I declare my field as long and value will come simply as `20118998631` then it will break.

```
    int x = 20118998631; // compilation error
    long l = 20118998631; // compilation error
    double d = 20118998631; // compilation error
    Long l1 = new Long(20118998631); // compilation error
```

Comment: *"...problem is that I am getting this from a network call and if I declare my field as long and value will come simply as 20118998631 then it will break"* -- can you tell the details about this, since this may be where the problem should be attacked.

Comment: If you are getting the value from a call then I don't see how the above literal declarations have anything to do with that. Consider showing an example that actually shows how you get that number and what error happens. As it currently stands all we can tell you is that in the above you are trying to declare invalid int literals, but that won't really help you solve your actual problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It is simply a REST call and I am de-serializing the result and where this particular field is deserialized is currenlty declared as INT, so I thought changing it to long will help but that is also compilation error, so I am sure that at runtime again I will get deserialization exception when 20118998631 will come in the result.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS if I have to hold this 20118998631 value in some primitive then how will I hold?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is as you mention network calls, but show assignments. `Long.MAX_VALUE` is set to `9223372036854775807` and `Long.MAX_VALUE > 20118998631L` is `true`. It can be stored as a long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that max value for int and long are very high

The definition of 'very' is in the eye of the beholder, isn't it?

The max value of an int is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which is 2147483647. Specifically, that's 2, to the 31st power, minus 1. Because computers use bits, `int` uses 32 bits, and about half of all the numbers an int can represent are used to represent *negative* numbers, hence why you end up with 2^31-1 as max int.

For longs, its 2^63-1 for the same reason: `long` uses 64 bit, and half of all representable values are negative.

If you have numbers that are larger than this, you need to use `BigInteger` (a class in the standard library for integers of arbitrary size) or `byte[]` or something else.

> but problem is that I am getting this from a network call and if I declare my field as long and value will come simply as 20118998631 then it will break.

This doesn't make sense. Are you getting stuff from the network, shoving what you get into a file with a prefix and suffix, and then that file is something you compile with `javac`? That sounds bonkers, but if you are, just.. add that `L`. Or, add `"` before and after the number and pass that to `new BigInteger` instead, now the number can be thousands of digits large if you want it to be.

Otherwise, you're getting a bytes which either represent the number directly (and the `L` aspect is not relevant to this conversation), or you're getting a string in, which again, isn't relevant to this conversation: That L is *just* for writing literal numbers inside `.java` files, it doesn't come up *anywhere else*. Turning a string containing digits, such as `"20118998631"` into e.g. a long is done with `Long.parseLong("20118998631")` which works fine, and does not require the L (in fact, it won't work if you include it).

Answer (score 1):

As people have already mentioned in the comments, we need more details about your networking in order to answer the question in full.

In general:

Your respons will be in form of a string (or byte array to be exact) and you will have to convert this to your representation.
You will have to use a function to convert the string to your desired representation, for example, `Long.valueOf("20118998631")` would do it.
But depending on the setup in use you might need to configure your networking to interpret the incoming number as long.

In general, most developers tend to use int for most things, so you might have code in your networking that tries to convert all numbers to int, which will not work with numbers larger than 2147483647, no matter what. The StackTrace should help in this case.

For the examples provided in your question:

```java
int x = 20118998631;
/*
compilation error, the number doesn't fit within an integer and never will.
Therefore expected.
*/

long l = 20118998631;
/*
compilation error, you assign to the variable l the integer constant 20118998631;
this will not work as the given integer is larger than max int.
Use 20118998631L (not the L) to use a long
*/

double d = 20118998631; 
/*
compilation error, same as with long above, use a capital D to interpret the number as double
*/

Long l1 = new Long(20118998631);
/*
compilation error
Same as with long above, you declare an integer constant larger than max int and box it within long.
Add a trailing L for long and preferably remove the boxing (java will auto-box if necessary)
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

So 20118998631L = 0x4_AF2F_8E67L which does not fit in a java `int` of 4 bytes, only in a `long`.

The REST API defines an INT and indeed in an SQL INT this might fit.

Getting the "INT" as String s you must do `Long.parseLong(s)`.

Getting the "INT" as bytes, then 04 might be a size (4 bytes), of 2939129447.